Power Logger for measuring wide current range(10uA-3A) using dual shunts
I am making a power logger to measure current from 10uA to 3A, I thought of using two shunts to make this possible. a 10kohm(for low currents) one and another of 10mohm( for high currents), I am using the INA240A amplifier with a gain of 50  for both of these, ADS1120 ADC converter and the ESP32 dev kit c to make this work. I understand I would need to use MOSFETs to switch between these two shunts and digital logic, but how will this work?where and how will this switch be placed?can someome provide me a picture because I am really confused about how to switch these. also, please dummy it down for me.
Feedback from supervisor: You route the power through one or the other shunt by using switches, either by digital control when the MCU detects the current is out of range or you implement automatic gain control using analog circuits that supervise the voltage over one shunt and enable another one when needed.
But I am confused about this feedback,can u explain what this means, can someone paint a clear picture for me
